# Merge matching elements attributes into single element

Tags: xslt, merge

I have the following markup.

```
<para><span class="bidi"/><span class="ind"/>1</para>
```

I'm trying to achieve this...

```
<para><span style="direction:rtl; text-indent:10pt;">1</span></para>
```

However, I'm getting this...

```
<para><span style="direction:rtl">1</span><span style="text-indent:10pt">1</span></para>
```

Here is my XSLT.

```
  <xsl:template match="span" name="spans">
        <span>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:choose>                
            <xsl:when test="@class eq 'bidi'">
                <xsl:text>direction:rtl</xsl:text>                
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@class eq 'ind'">
                <xsl:text>text-indent:10pt;</xsl:text>                
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
```

How do I merge the multiple spans into 1 with all of their class attribute values?

Comment: Which XSLT version do you target? It seems to be a job for XSLT 2.0's `for-each-group group-adjacent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="para[span]">
     <para>
       <span>
          <xsl:attribute name="style">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="span"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::span)]"/>
       </span>
     </para>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="span[@class='bidi']">
  <xsl:if test="position() >1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>direction:rtl;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="span[@class='ind']">
  <xsl:if test="position() >1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>text-indent:10pt;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<para><span class="bidi"/><span class="ind"/>1</para>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<para><span style="direction:rtl; text-indent:10pt;">1</span></para>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thanks as always for a great response.  However, this works for para level attributes (which I can test for), but I'm looking to retain the <span> element wrapped around the content for inline attributes (i.e. bold, italic).

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks. This works.  What would be the best way to test if an individual span had an attribute called paraProperty?

Comment: @Jeff: If this `span` is the current node, the test is simly `"@paraProperty"` -- as in `<xsl:if test="@paraProperty">` .

Comment: @Dimitri I'm testing from the parent node which is changing because I'm in a for-each.  Would it be something like child::span or node()span?

Comment: @Jeff: I need to see your code -- it would be best if you ask a new question, as the comment format isn't convenient for sharing code. How about accepting this answer?

Comment: @Jeff: You are welcome. I will be glad to look at your next question -- please, let me know when you have it posted.